# What is the relationship between $S0(2)$ and $PSL(2,R)$?

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, group-isomorphism, hyperbolic-geometry

The Holonomy of a hyperbolic surface S in terms of differential geometry is either $SO(2)$ or $O(2)$ depending on Orientability. And a hyperbolic structure as a special (X,G)-structure: $\pi_1(S)⊂PSL(2,R)$. (An $(X,G)$ structure could be regarded as a flat X-bundle with a section transversal to the flat connection, so holonomy of the flat bundle is the holonomy of the structure.)

So there are two ways of describing the Holonomy of a Hyperbolic structure. But, are they both equally as valid in all cases? And what is the relationship between SO(2) and PSL(2,R)?

Comment: $SO(2,\Bbb{R})$ comes from parallel transporting a vector $v$ at $p$ along the sides of an hyperbolic triangle with one vertex at $p$, the angle defect of the triangle will cause the image of $v$ to be slightly rotated. Can you explain the second part?

Comment: Cross-posted at MO [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/391593/what-is-the-relationship-between-mathrmso2-and-mathrmpsl2-mathbbr?noredirect=1#comment998699_391593).

Answer (score 1):

$SO(2)$ is the maximal compact subgroup of $PSL(2, \mathbb{R}).$